# Angularjs / REST api - call api to display obj data based on another object in selector

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a SPA website to display softball stats for the softball teams I manage. This specific questions is related to using angularjs to display the results of an api call, where the api call is based on what is selected in a selector.

The two models I am working with:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string WeekNight { get; set; }
    public int? Year { get; set; }

    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public int LeagueId { get; set; }

    public virtual Manager Manager { get; set; }
    public virtual League League { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Award> Awards { get; set; }
}

public class Award
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AwardTypeId { get; set; }
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual AwardType AwardType { get; set; }
    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

}
```

In part of my view I have the following which creates a selector and populates it with all of my teams:

```js
var teamService = angular.module('teamService', ['ngResource']);

teamService.factory('Team', ['$resource',

  function($resource) {
    return $resource('api/v1/teams/:teamId', {}, {
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          teamId: '@teamId'
        },
        isArray: true
      },
      post: {
        method: 'POST'
      },
      update: {
        method: 'PUT',
        params: {
          teamId: '@teamId'
        }
      },
      remove: {
        method: 'DELETE'
      }
    });
  }
]);;


var teamController = angular.module('teamController', []);

teamController.controller('teamListController', ['$scope', 'Team',
  function($scope, Team) {
    $scope.teams = Team.query();
  }
]);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="award-team-select col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control" ng-controller="teamListController">
      <option ng-repeat="t in teams">{{t.year}} - {{t.name}} ({{t.weekNight}}'s)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Connected to my webAPI this works correctly and will return something like:

2015 - SomeTeamName (Monday's)

Cool. Now underneath that I want to display the awards for that selected team. I have a working url created as such:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "TeamAwards",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/teams/{id}/awards/{awardId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "award", awardId = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Using Googles Advanced Rest Cient I can get the awards for a specific team... and here is where I am struggling. Underneath the selector I have some pretty formatted divs to display the awards. I want to show the awards for the team in the selector.

I tried adding another function to my factory that calls the "api/v1/teams/{id}/awards/{awardId}" url but I am not sure how to get the teamId from the selector linked into the new factory function. I was then going to make a 'teamAwardController' that gets the data from the factory to be displayed in the divs below the selector.

In short I want to be able to display awards, where awards.teamId == the Id of the team in the selector.

Any advice would be awesome.
Thanks!

Adding an edit:

So based on current feed back I am also taking a stab at accessing the child awards in the TeamController. So if I have:

```
 <div ng-controller="teamController">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="award-team-select col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
       <select class="form-control">
         <option ng-repeat="t in teams">{{t.year}} - {{t.name}} ({{t.weekNight}}'s) </option>
       </select>
     </div>
   </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      // awards to go here
  </div>

</div>  // end teamController div
```

... I tried using ng-model="teams" up in the teamController and then ng-bind="teams" in the awards section as well as trying {{teams.awards}} but no dice. Am I way off here?

Comment: Have you considered simply returning the awards as part of the teams list? It looks like your `Team` model already has the awards as children.

Comment: I was looking at doing this but It would have to be in a nested ng-repeat. my issue is that the ng-repeat for teams is in a select tag which is closed and so is its parent div. Then further down another div is where I am trying to display the awards.

Comment: So basically you need a way to get the selected team ID, pass that into your `teamAwardController` within which you will call your API to get the team's awards. Is that right?

Comment: Yup! so the drop down uses teamController which calls api/v1/teams/{id}. Then I would have a teamAwardsController which calls api/v1/teams/{teamId}/awards/{id}. But I don't know how to populate teamID.  Also, I have been trying to just use the TeamController and get awards via the child attributes but I am unsure how to get them. I am still in under the div containing the TeamController, I tried using ng-model="teams" and then using ng-bind down in the awards div, but no luck.

Comment: Check out the answer I provided below - you can maintain your separate controller modules. I'm not sure where or how you were trying to use `ng-model` and `ng-bind` in your updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the [`<select>`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) to a variable in your controller, then use that variable to display the correct awards. Something like this:

```
 <div ng-controller="teamController">
   <div>
       <select ng-model="selectedTeamId">
         <option ng-repeat="t in teams" value="{{t.id}}">{{...}}</option>
       </select>
   </div>

  <div>
      // awards to go here
      {{awardInfo}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript：

```
teamController.controller('teamListController', ['$scope', 'Team', 'Award',
    function($scope, Team, Award) {

        $scope.teams = Team.query();
        $scope.selectedTeamId = null;
        $scope.awardInfo = null;

        $scope.$watch('selectedTeamId', function(idValue) {
            if (idValue !== null) {
                $scope.awardInfo = Award.query({ teamId: idValue });
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to share the selected team ID between controllers, you have to use something to accomplish this. Angular has several options for this, but in this case I think a value would suffice. Also, I would switch your `select` to use `ng-options` to make this whole process easier.

There are many ways to implement this, but here is one sample that should help get you started. I faked up some data and also everything is just using one large angular.module() chain, both of which you probably should not do in a production app.

I'm using a value to share the team ID between the controllers. A value is nothing more than a persistent object that you can inject in any of your Angular modules. In the `teamAwardsController` I am watching for a change in the `SelectedTeam.id` property - you'll have to handle when no team is selected, but that should be easy. In `teamListController` I assign the `SelectedTeam` value to a `$scope` level variable so that it can be read and set directly in the view.

First the JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .value('SelectedTeam', {
        id: -1
    })
    .service('FakeDataService', function() {
        this.GetTeams = function() {
            return [{
                id: 1,
                name: 'Portland Timbers',
                weekNight: 'Monday',
                year: '2016'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Seattle Sounders',
                weekNight: 'Tuesday',
                year: '2016'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                name: 'LA Galaxy',
                weekNight: 'Thursday',
                year: '2016'
            }, {
                id: 4,
                name: 'San Jose Quakes',
                weekNight: 'Wednesday',
                year: '2016'
            }, ];
        };
    })
    .controller('teamListController', function($scope, FakeDataService, SelectedTeam) {
        $scope.selectedTeam = SelectedTeam;
        $scope.teams = FakeDataService.GetTeams();
    })
    .controller('teamAwardsController', function($scope, $log, SelectedTeam) {
        $scope.selectedTeam = SelectedTeam;
        $scope.$watch('selectedTeam.id', function() {
            $log.info('Team changed to ' + $scope.selectedTeam.id);
        });
    });
```

And now some sample markup:

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller='teamListController'>
        <select ng-model='selectedTeam.id' ng-options='t.id as (t.year + " - " + t.name + " (" + t.weekNight + "s)") for t in teams'></select>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller='teamAwardsController'>
        Here is where would list the selected team's awards.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK. I got it! The answer you have here is what I originally had in mind for how I would get the data, but your very first comment to my OP really does make the most sense and that's what Mikes solution does. I implemented this solution first, but since both controllers have the selectedTeam param I simply expand the div containing the controller reference to contain the awards dive and then used Mikes solution below. Thanks for all the help!